# Apple Calendar on Venture - viewing delegated calendars fails

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, caldav, macos-ventura

We have a - very old - iCal server running on a local machine (Snow Leopard).

We're using Apple's Calendar-App on iMacs and MacBooks. Connecting to the server works. We're using port 8008 without SSL, since Snow Leopard uses an old ssl-version that's not compatible anymore.

We can see our own calendars just fine.
However: When we try to connect to delegated calendars it fails. I found out that delegated calendars are accessed via `dataaccessd`. Using proxyman it showed that `dataaccessd` always uses `https` on port `8443`, no matter how the CalDAV-Account is configured.

This worked up to MacOS Monterey. As soon as some of us switched to Ventura, the above issues started.

Any ideas how to tell `dataaccessd` (and `accountsd` as well) to use the connection defined in the account?